# Calculating and identifying "desirable" routes through directed graph

Tags: graph-theory

Forgive the vague title, it's been a few years since I've done any Mathematics related to this area and my terminology is fairly lacking (part of why I'm asking this question). I'm sure there's a well defined algorithm/theory that already deals with what I'm trying to achieve, but I can't quite pin down the words to find it.

I'll try and describe the situation I'm modelling:

Given a group of items [a,b,c,d,e,f], a person may be offering to trade certain items, e.g. I may swap you "a" for "b", and you may be offering "2xc" for an "e". I can scoop up all these trades and create a graph outlining the options on offer. I'm interested in looking for particular trade paths, and as an aside, trade paths that would give me surplus items - I assume this sort of thing must already exist in the financial sector (again, I'm missing the names/experience of the mathematics).

so if I had "a" and wanted "f", and I had the following paths available:

```
a -> b, b -> f, c -> b, a-> 2(c), b -> a
```

I'd end up with

```
a -> b -> f

a -> (2)c -> b -> f    
      |
      c             (An additional c)
```

There may places where I could cycle repeatedly, so if I used the b -> a relation above, I could continually extract c because of the surplus c item.

I'm reasonably sure I can write a program to do this, but I'm a big fan of understanding the correct terminology and methodology behind problems like this one. If anyone can point me in the right direction for a particular topic to read about, or a if there's a obvious name for what it is I'm trying to achieve, I'd be very grateful.

Apologies again for the vague-ness.

Comment: The keyword for the "continually extracting" part is "arbitrage".

Comment: Cracking, thanks =D Definitely makes articulating questions a little easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a typical [state space search](http://www.cs.trincoll.edu/~ram/cpsc352/notes/search.html) problem. Algorithms like [BFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) or [iterative deepening](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_deepening_depth-first_search) can find the shortest series of trades, or even generate all possibilities.

To apply these algorithms, you'll have to redefine your graph. Instead of using nodes like `a` and `b` with an edge `a -> b`, define a state space where a state consists of a finite number of each of the elements `{a, b, c, f}` (in this case, a four-tuple of integers would suffice) and a successor function *S* that applies all possible trades given a state and constructs a set of successors states. E.g., in pseudo-Python notation,

```
S({a: 1, b: 2, c: 0, f: 0}) = [{a: 0, b: 3, c: 0, f: 0},   # trade a for b
                               {a: 1, b: 1, c: 0, f: 1},   # trade b for f
                               {a: 1, b: 2, c: 2, f: 0},   # trade a for 2c
                               {a: 2, b: 1, c: 0, f: 0}]   # trade b for a
```

Since state-space search is a classical paradigm in AI, most AI textbooks cover it. In particular, I can recommend [*AIMA* by Russell and Norvig](http://aima.cs.berkeley.edu/), which spends its first few chapters discussing state space search in quite some detail.

Comment: That's an interesting approach, and it looks like the sort of thing I'd been naively trying to grasp the wording for. It also looks like this will inherently deal with another issue I was wondering about, relating to item quantities (how many times I could use a particular path).
 Thanks for the links and pointers, I've got some reading to do =D